# Does the conditional statement "If not-p then p" have a name?

Tags: logic

For there to be not-p it is necessary that there be p.  It is easy to show that "If not-p then p" is true, and conversely "If p then not-p" is false.  Further the contra-positive of "If not-p then p" is itself.

If this is already known what it is called?

Comment: "If not-p then p" is generally false, just take p="1+1=3". Indeed, it has the same truth value as p itself.

Comment: In classical logic, "If not-P then P" is logically equivalent to "P or P", so its truth value is the truth value of P, as Conifold points out in his comment.

Comment: Before I reply a correction "If p then not-p" is true if p is false, hence it is unsound rather than false as I claimed.  Interpretations of p aside we cannot deny p if there is no p to deny.  Hence p is a necessary condition for not-p and so not-p is a sufficient condition for p, and we express this logically as given.  Logically you can have p without not-p but not vice versa.  Modus ponens "If not-p then p. p. Therefore not-p" where p is true of course.

Comment: Just a correction to modus ponens "If not-p then p.  Not-p.  Therefore p."

Comment: No; no name.....

Comment: To clarify and put the question to rest. It is trivial to show that "(not-P implies P) iff P" is a tautology. There are two cases we need to consider 1) when the opposites are contrary and 2) when the opposites are contradictory.  For case 1) consider Left(L)/Right(R).  It follows that "(L & R) iff ((L implies R) & (R implies L)).  In the second case consider "(Satan exists implies God exists) iff God exists".

Comment: Correction to 1) above we have L iff R and this is equivalent to ((L implies R)&(R implies L)).  Regarding words we have "W iff not-W" to mean opposites, rather than negation.  This is not the case in 2) where "not-God (Satan) implies God".

Comment: This question can be deleted as there is nothing of relevance here.  That is, this is just "material implication" but with the truth table restricted to those rows where p is opposite q say.  Thanks Conifold and Nick for your comments.